# Generating tables for each factor level over a range of columns, in R with dplyr and reshape2

Tags: r, function, dplyr, reshape2

For a range of columns (variables) in a data frame, I need to generate tables for each level of each variable. I have created a function that finds the first column in the range (Q1a) and then runs a for loop for every column after. The loop finds the number of levels in each column and then a second for loop is supposed to generate the table and save it as a .csv with a unique file name.

Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Organization = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"), Q1a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Q1b = c(1, 2, 1, 2))
```

df Returns:

```
  Organization Gender Q1a Q1b
1            A   Male   1   1
2            B Female   2   2
3            C   Male   3   1
4            D Female   4   2
```

Here is the function I wrote:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
f = function(df) {
  a <- which(colnames(df) == "Q1a")
  for(i in colnames(df[, a:length(df)])) {
      levelsList <- as.list(levels(i))
      for(j in levelsList) {
          temp <- subset(df, i == j, select = c(Organization, Gender, i))
          temp <- group_by(temp, Organization, Gender)
          table <- summarize(temp, count = n())
          table <- dcast(table, Organization ~ Gender)
          table <- mutate(table, Total = Female + Male)
          write.csv(table, paste0(i, "_", j, ".csv"))
      }
   }
}
```

The expected output for a larger dataset would look like:

```
    Organization    Female  Male    Total
1          A          366    259      625
2          B          30     35       65
3          C          83     61       144
4          D          55     58       113
```

I can generate a single table like the one above correctly with a few lines of code. The problem is that the function does not generate any files. Am I on the right track? Is there an easier way to do this using apply?

Comment: please include your expected output. It is not clear from your post.

Comment: You are missing the closing parenthesis on `write.csv`.

Comment: This isn't, IMO, an appropriate question for SO. Basic issues, like making sure parentheses are all closed, should be fixed before posting a question.

Comment: You are correct. My apologies. However, making that edit does not make the script functional. I have appended my submission appropriately. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues that I changed. Take a look at what the value of `i` is in your loop. It's the string value of the column name from `df`. When passed to `levels()` all you will ever get is `NULL`. If you really want to use `levels()` you need to convert those columns to factors, or else substitute `unique()`.

See the warning section under `?subset` for using this function, I've changed the code to use `[` for subsetting the data frame.

Also, I assumed that you meant to output `table` to the CSV instead of `org.sum` which does not exist in your example.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(Organization = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D"), Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female"), Q1a = as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)), Q1b = as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
f = function(df) {
  a <- which(colnames(df) == "Q1a")
  for(i in colnames(df[, a:length(df)])) {
    levelsList <- levels(df[,i])
    for(j in levelsList) {
      temp <- df[df[,i] == j, c('Organization', 'Gender', i)] 
      temp <- group_by(temp, Organization, Gender)
      table <- summarize(temp, count = n())
      table <- dcast(table, Organization ~ Gender, value.var='count')
      if (dim(table)[2] > 2) {table$Total <- rowSums(table[,c('Male', 'Female')])}
      else {table$Total <- table[,2]}
      write.csv(table, paste0(i, "_", j, ".csv"), row.names = F)
    }
  }
}

f(df)
```

Comment: Using unique() instead of levels() in your solution worked beautifully. Your subsetting tweak was definitely the missing piece. And yes, org.sum is a typo. Thank you for the helpful response! Cheers.